# Onsen UI, how to use isShow() Method

Tags: javascript, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

I'm creating a very simple app, and I'm using Onsen UI and purely JavaScript (no Angular, React, or Vue). This is the first time a use this framework, but so far seems pretty simple and straight forward, except the `isShow()` method. I have a dialog that I open using:

```
document.getElementById(id).show({ animation: "fade" });
```

But now I need to know how to check if the dialog is open or not. I thought that using something like this would work:

```
console.log(document.getElementById(id).isShown());
```

But I get a `document.getElementById(...).isShown is not a function` error message.The only thing I can find is what is says inn the Onsen UI documentation: `isShown() Returns whether the popover is visible or not.`

How can I determine if a Dialog `<ons-dialog>` element is open (visible) in Onsen UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isShown()` method was part of Onsen UI **v1**. For **v2** you can access `visible` property and get the same value. [Docs here](https://onsen.io/v2/api/js/ons-dialog.html#properties).

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try. In the meantime I used an answer that you gave a while ago: `el.style.display !== 'none'`, and `window.getComputedStyle(el)` also worked.